# Spring boot restarting and creating applicationContext for each test class

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, junit5

Maven surefire plugin:

```
   <includes>
     <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
```

Base class:

```
@autoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ApplicationTests {
}
```

This class is extended by all test classes, which are usually of following syntex:

```
@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ATestClass extends ApplicationTests {
 
@Test
//test method
}
```

When I do >mvn clean package
All tests run but for each class the boot application restarts, asif its recreating ApplicationContext for each test (Or something else), so it take an hour for build to complete.

How to run all tests in single go.

Comment: Your `ATestClass` doensn't extend anything, nor do you need `@ExtendWith`. The context will be cached unless you are using different variations of `@MockBean`,`@@TestPropertySource` and others that will lead to creation of a new context as well. The fact that you have many of those you might want to reconsider the usage of `@SpringBootTest` and write simpler unit tests instead of ull blown integration tests.

Comment: public class ATestClass extends ApplicationTests {